# Unable to distract the guards using gas?

Tags: call-of-cthulhu

In "Call of Cthulhu" (2018; on PC), I'm trying to escape the Riverside Asylum. I've gotten the two wheel and attached them to the pipes, and activated all four pipes, but when I pull the lever by the last wheel, Edward just says "What happened? I must try something else."

I went back and checked all the pipes, and 3 of them are showing in the 'danger' section of the dial. The one closest to the stairs (nearest to the kitchen) doesn't show the needle in the 'danger' area, but I can't interact with any of the wheels (or the lever) at all.

**Did I do something wrong? Can I still use gas to distract the guards?** I did make sure to turn this particular wheel first, so I know I did interact with it. I tried reloading from the last checkpoint, but that just left me in an odd state where the lever hadn't been pulled, but I can't interact with it.

[image: The lever, uninteractable]